# what is the fastest way to rotate a bmp image in C?

Tags: bmp

I'm creating a photo edit app and i was wondering..How can I rotate a bmp pic fast? I mean what's the quickest piece of code to rotate it by 90 degrees?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it boils down to rotating a matrix, or a 2 dimensional matrix.
Which means that you have to do O(n * m) operations, when the image has dimension n * m.

Comment: meaning? :/ i've never used these operations before..is there a tutorial?

Comment: What I wanted to say is that whatever you do, you need at least k * n * m simple operations.

Answer (score 0):

Paint has a few pieces of code that will do the things required pretty fast, depending on your dexterity.